# ESP-IDF idf.py works fine with the provided cmd but does not working in VS Code

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I just started with ESP_IDF and when I run idf.py using the ESP-IDF command port everything works fine. But when I run the command in the terminal in VS Code it gives an error that \python.exe is not recognized.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKxJF.png)
Python command works fine. I am using the latest ESP-IDF v 5.1 and also have Espressif IDF extension installed in VS Code and have my settings.json set up as:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always",
    "idf.gitPathWin": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\idf-git\\2.39.2\\cmd\\git.exe",
    "idf.espIdfPathWin": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\esp\\esp-idf",
    "idf.pythonBinPathWin": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\python_env\\idf5.1_py3.8_env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "idf.toolsPathWin": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif",
    "idf.customExtraPaths": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp-elf-gdb\\12.1_20221002\\xtensa-esp-elf-gdb\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\riscv32-esp-elf-gdb\\12.1_20221002\\riscv32-esp-elf-gdb\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\esp-12.2.0_20230208\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\\esp-12.2.0_20230208\\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32s3-elf\\esp-12.2.0_20230208\\xtensa-esp32s3-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\riscv32-esp-elf\\esp-12.2.0_20230208\\riscv32-esp-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\esp32ulp-elf\\2.35_20220830\\esp32ulp-elf\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\cmake\\3.24.0\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\openocd-esp32\\v0.12.0-esp32-20230419\\openocd-esp32\\bin;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\ninja\\1.10.2;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\idf-exe\\1.0.3;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\ccache\\4.8\\ccache-4.8-windows-x86_64;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\dfu-util\\0.11\\dfu-util-0.11-win64;C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\esp-rom-elfs\\20230320",
    "idf.customExtraVars": {
        "OPENOCD_SCRIPTS": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\openocd-esp32\\v0.12.0-esp32-20230419/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts",
        "IDF_CCACHE_ENABLE": "1",
        "ESP_ROM_ELF_DIR": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\tools\\esp-rom-elfs\\20230320/"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [
                "/k",
                "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\idf_cmd_init.bat"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
    },
    "idf.pythonBinPath": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\python_env\\idf5.1_py3.8_env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\SyeMo\\.espressif\\python_env\\idf5.1_py3.8_env\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

I have tried changing the python folder in the python interceptor but it did not help.